# program stuck using drag and drop selenium

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop

I am trying to move slider using drag and drop. It identifies the element and clicked on it and after that nothing happens and my code stuck there itself(like waiting for user input). As soon as i moved my mouse little bit manually it executes rest of the code and works as expected. please help me what is this weird behavior.?. below is the code i used to build drag and drop.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action secondSlide = builder.dragAndDropBy(secondSlider, 50, 0).click().build();
    System.out.println("waiting");
    secondSlide.perform();
    System.out.println("not waiting");
```

"Waiting" message is printing nicely but it doesn't print "not waiting" as it stuck in "secondSlide.perform()" line. But as soon as i moves my mouse little bit manually it prints "not waiting" and program ends gracefully.

Comment: I think its problem with widget not with code.

Comment: I am facing same issue now. How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it differently. Here is a number of approaches:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("element dom name")); 
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target dom name"));
(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

Or:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
   .moveToElement(otherElement)
   .release(otherElement)
   .build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```